# Running python script unlimitedly on cloud

Tags: python, cloud

I want a cloud platform to run a python script but most platforms I see has some limitations that don't allow unlimited CPU usage for a long time. is there any platform that allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from https://colab.research.google.com/ , depending on your usage requirement and project, you can check out https://replit.com/~ for staging your python script. After writing your main script, say *main.py*, you need to create another *.py* file and add the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello. I am alive!" #this will be printed in the webview of the replit interface.

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
```

After this you need to add the *keep_alive* function to the last line of your *main.py*.
Then, run the script and copy the address from the webview of replit (It is like an internal browser window).

Go to https://uptimerobot.com/ and after creating an account, *Add new monitor* and select Monitor type as HTTP(s), give a name, and paste the address in the URL. Check your email-id for getting notifications regarding the status of the monitor, and finally create it.

You are done!
Hopefully it should work.

All the best!